# How to Create Table in Sqlite from Java Code?

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I can manage colum (like insert, update or delete) from pre-created table in Sqlite from java code. But i want to create a new table from code. How Can I do that..?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it.  Better to add data by inserting into an existing schema.  Better to reconsider your design to not require table creation in Java.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-create-tables.htm)

Comment: Another option is to have a stored procedure doing the DML (Table creation) and invoke the stored procedure from Java using JDBC which is copacetic. Absolutely nothing wrong in doing this if that is your requirement.

Comment: Let me know if you need any assistance with the stored procedure approach.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.